# Start without debugging doesn't run - blank cmd - and after an error on any attempt to run

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2015 Community

So I am new to Visual Studio completely. It works perfectly on my desktop, but I am having this problem on my laptop. Here is the gist of it -

I just write something to print the numbers 0 - 10. If I hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, it builds and flashes on the screen real quick, as expected. Next, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F5</kbd> - cmd opens and is blank, just the flashing line. It does not run. I close the cmd window (have tried just hitting return/any key on the blank window). After closing, if I try to run it again, either <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F5</kbd>, I get the error:

> Could not copy "obj\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe" to "bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.

I have looked around for a solution and even though both of these separate issues are talked about, cannot find any solution to either of them.
If I go to task manager, I have several ConsoleApplication2.exe*32 processes - I can kill all of them but two. No matter what I do I cannot terminate them, and cannot delete the src/bin folders as I saw someone suggest.

Further, even if I figure out how to kill these processes so I can run again, it still doesn't help me with why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F5</kbd> just doesn't run.

Can anyone help or point me in a direction to a possible cause for this? I tried repairing, uninstalling and reinstalling, and several other suggestions and nothing seems to work. I am going crazy trying to get this to work.

Comment: Have you considered the differences between the two systems? For example, if they are running different anti-virus programs, you might need to exclude the appropriate VS projects folder from the AV on the laptop. (P.S. if you put `Console.ReadLine()` as the last line in your program it will stay open until you press the Enter key.)

Answer (score -1):

I think it's your anti-virus .. especially if you're using Avast. It causes the same issue for me.
To solve it add exclusion to your anti-virus:

[image]